# Prevent iframe navigation and get the link in React

Tags: reactjs, iframe, navigation

I've a Reactjs component with a Seakbeak vr tour displayed in an iframe. Vr tour also has some links inside and when clicked target links are opened at the top window. What I want to achieve is **preventing navigation** (sandbox works here) but **getting the target link**.

*If necesary I can purchase Seakbeak domain addon which enables the iframe src to be same domain but I cannot edit iframe link targets directly.*

Comment: When you say `navigation`, you mean the navigation inside iframe? and what is the target link. Please add a bit more details, and hopefully share you iframe code.

Comment: https://seekbeak.com/v/NkjxBlPy1lQ?start_rot_x=-0.05894&start_rot_y=-0.19967&start_rot_z=0.00000&start_rot_order=YXZ
this is an example of iframe src. If you follow the the link you will see there are hotspots and when you click on them you will be redirected in a new tab. One of the hostspot target is https://eys.mavimor.com.tr/EkipmanDetay.aspx?id=20550&a=#20550. So I want to be able to get this link (indeed I just need id part in this url).